# Breezejs: nest zValidate inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, breeze

So, have created a few angular directives -- picture "user controls" around common data entry elements, like a label-textbox pair, etc

The problem we are having is that the zValidate directive does not seem to work from within the directive.  Is there something we need to do to make nested directives work?

**Edit**
Here are the relevant code snippets.

So, first, we have a little directive that adds a label-input pair:

```
app.directive('afLabelInputPair', function ($compile) {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {                    //@textValue    =twoWayBinding      &oneWayBinding
            labelText: '@labelText',
            afModel: '=',
            afId: '@',
            afPlaceholder: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: './app/templates/af-label-input-pair.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.opts = attrs;
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }

    return directive;
});
```

Next, we have the template html (this is what's returned from templateUrl:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="{{afId}}">{{labelText}}</label>
    <input id="{{afId}}" class="form-control" ng-model="afModel" placeholder="{{afPlaceholder}}" data-z-validate />
</div>
```

But, we don't get a display of breeze validation errors when we use this directive.

Comment: Do you have a code sample of what you are saying is not working?

Comment: I added the code for the directive.

Comment: I appreciate any help you can give. The breeze part is pretty well baked but the Ng part ... not so much. The zValidate directive is a work-in-progress and the progress has been minimal due to insufficient priority. This is an open source project. Feel free to contribute.

Comment: Thank's Ward -- if we can figure out what's going on, we'll submit a fix.

Comment: Afraid not -- ended up on a different project that does not use Breeze, so no longer researching it.